# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate not substituting values?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am new to Spring and trying to write a simple test method that uses NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Here it is:

```
public String test() {
    String query = "SELECT CURRENT DATE FROM :table ;";
    return String.valueOf(this.namedTemplate.queryForObject(query,
        new MapSqlParameterSource("table", "sysibm.sysdummy1"),
            String.class));
}
```

In DB2, that query should return today's date. However, I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT CURRENT DATE FROM ?
>   ;]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException:
>   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=?;( 
>   XMLTABLE TABLE FINAL OLD, DRIVER=4.13.127

SQLCODE -104 is "illegal symbol." I guess this is referring to the `?`. Why is it getting that instead of the `"sysibm.sysdummy1"` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set table name as parameter. You need explicit define it in your query.

Comment: Ah ha. Thank you. Does that also apply to schema names?

Comment: Yes. In PreparedStatement only parameters can be defined using '?'.